# Read A Directory To Fetch A Single File Name Or Read A Single File To Fetch A New Line When A Match Is Found

Tags: php

I am developing the front-end of an app and I have a colleague developing the back-end along sides me.

My front-end is built with React JS over PHP, reasons being that I want to avoid using local storage to save some information like my JWT tokens for example. So I decided to insert them into files. So it's some what like a file session too.

**Question**

Currently, I create a new file with a unique file name (`usermail@example.com_session`) for an authenticated user and then I save some information into the file. So this means that I would have a unique file for every authenticated user. I would like to find out which is a more expensive/better process as regards memory usage. For example:

1. Would it be better to read a large file of 50k Line of entries and search for a unique identifier on newlines.
2. Or would it be better to read a directory containing 50k really light weight files and search for a particular unique identifier as a file name. (This is the currently what been implemented)

Lastly, Here's my sample code over PHP for better understanding of how i'm going about it.

```
namespace Controllers;

require_once rootPath . '/Config/BaseUrl.php';
require_once rootPath . '/Config/ApiUrl.php';
require_once rootPath . '/Config/RateLimiter.php';

use Config\RateLimiter;
use Config\BaseUrl;
use Config\ApiUrl;

/***
 * MainController;
 */

class MainController
{
    protected static string $sessionID = "";
    protected static $AuthUser = false;
    protected static $fileSessionID = "";
    protected static string $filePath = rootPath . "/Logs/sessions/";

    public function __construct() 
    {
        self::beginSession();
        self::$sessionID = self::currentSessionID();
        self::$AuthUser = isset($_SESSION['authUser']) ? $_SESSION['authUser'] : false;
        if(self::$AuthUser != false && is_array(self::$AuthUser)) // Only one session allowed
            self::compareSessionID();
    }
    
    private static function beginSession() : void
    {
        if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }
    }

    protected static function currentSessionID() : string 
    {
        return session_id();
    }
    
    protected static function regenerateSessionID() : string
    {
        return session_regenerate_id();
    }

    protected static function saveSessionID() : void
    {
        self::$fileSessionID = fopen(self::$filePath . self::$AuthUser['email'] . "_session_id.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite(self::$fileSessionID, self::$sessionID);
        fclose(self::$fileSessionID);
    }

    protected static function getSessionID() : string
    {
        if(self::$AuthUser == false)
            return null;
        self::$fileSessionID = fopen(self::$filePath . self::$AuthUser['email'] . "_session_id.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = fgets(self::$fileSessionID);
        fclose(self::$fileSessionID);
        return $txt;
    }

    protected static function compareSessionID() : void
    {
        if(self::$AuthUser != false) {
            self::$fileSessionID = fopen(self::$filePath . self::$AuthUser['email'] . "_session_id.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
            if(fgets(self::$fileSessionID) != self::$sessionID) 
                self::logout();
            fclose(self::$fileSessionID);
        }
    } 

    protected static function changeSessionID() : void
    {
        if(self::$AuthUser == false) {
            self::$sessionID = self::$currentSessionID();
            self::saveSessionID();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question about this code? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Also, what's the reason for mixing so much stuff into one controller? Handling sessions, redirects, and cURL requests in a single class looks like bad design - better split this up into multiple classes

Comment: "how expensive is it" - what does that mean? Expensive in terms of....? Also, without knowing anything about the code these classes use, it's impossible to answer that question

Comment: @NicoHaase Oh, I'm not stuck. I added it to illustrate how I am implementing my code, because I want to be sure that it's not problematic. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: If you are not stuck, what's your question about all that code? Can you reduce your question to the **relevant** parts, such that these are better understandable?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm on it

Comment: @NicoHaase I've editted the question. Is that better?

Comment: I still don't get your problem. If you want to store data per user, a database would be the best way. Also, if your directory contains 50k files and you want to read a specific one, why should there be any need to "search" for that file? Why not simply open it, regardless of the number of files in that directory?

Comment: @NicoHaase Alright it looks like I was getting it wrong. I thought opening a file using `fopen` from a directory with many files was similar to searching for a file within that directory. So I was thinking that before a system would open a file with a certain name within a directory it had to filter through before matching the name of the file you wanted. Similar to `SELECT` statement in `SQL`. And so I assumed that it would become more memory consuming as the directory grows larger.

Comment: If you assume that, why not try it out and see what happens? Also, a `SELECT` statement won't iterate over all rows either if you used a proper index